# When writing to text file (appending) the last value I write replaces all previous values

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite, nsfilemanager

I'm trying to reproduce my SQLite3 table as a .csv file that is saved into the phones documents.

In order to do this I have attempted to append a new line to the end of the file, each time an object is found in my array, this works - however it seems to reproduce the last line over and over again for the exact number of rows in my sql table.

Here is the SQLite Select query:

```
    NSMutableArray *allGPS = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    GPS *gps = [[GPS alloc] init];
// Open the database from the users filessytem
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"GPS.db"];
    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &databaseHandle) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM GPSJob;"];
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseHandle, [sqlStatement UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"Statement prepared");
            while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {
                [gps setJobNo:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,0)]];
                [gps setSourceMonitor:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)]];
                [gps setPositionNo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sqlite3_column_int(statement,2)]];
                [gps setLatitude:sqlite3_column_double(statement, 3)];
                [gps setLongitude:sqlite3_column_double(statement, 4)];
                NSLog(@"Source Monitor: %@", [gps sourceMonitor]);
                [allGPS addObject:gps];
            }
        }
                    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
```

Here is the write to .csv file method:

```
 GPS *saveGPS = [[GPS alloc] init];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@.csv", jobNo]];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
    NSFileHandle *myHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];
    DataController *dataController = [[DataController alloc] init];
    NSString *csvTitleString =@"Source/Monitor, PositionNumber, Latitude, Longitude \n";
    [myHandle seekToEndOfFile];
    [myHandle writeData:[csvTitleString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSString *csvString = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSArray *allGPS = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[dataController getAll]];
    for(int i=0;i<(allGPS.count);i++){
        saveGPS = [allGPS objectAtIndex:i];
        csvString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %d, %f, %f \n", [saveGPS sourceMonitor], [[saveGPS positionNo] intValue], [saveGPS latitude], [saveGPS longitude]];
        [myHandle seekToEndOfFile];
        [myHandle writeData:[csvString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: Maybe create e new instance of `gps` in every iteration? 

while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
{
      gps = [[GPS alloc] init];
      [gps setJobNo:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char 
      ...
      ...
}

Comment: If you'd have posted that as an answer you would have got the bounty :(

Comment: Noooooooo :(
Oh well, never mind ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using always the same instance of `GPS` in the repeat loop so due to reference semantics the data in the object are overwritten and the same object is added to the array in each iteration.

Move the line

```
GPS *gps = [[GPS alloc] init];
```

just before the line

```
[gps setJobNo:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,0)]];
```

to create a new `GPS` instance in each iteration

Answer (score 3):

Create a new instance of the `gps`-object in every iteration:

```
while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
{
     gps = [[GPS alloc] init];

     [gps setJobNo:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,0)]];
     [gps setSourceMonitor:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)]];
     [gps setPositionNo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sqlite3_column_int(statement,2)]];
     [gps setLatitude:sqlite3_column_double(statement, 3)];
     [gps setLongitude:sqlite3_column_double(statement, 4)];
     NSLog(@"Source Monitor: %@", [gps sourceMonitor]);
     [allGPS addObject:gps];
 }
```